# (Excel VBA) Loop for specified period of time

Tags: excel, vba, loops, time

I'm trying to build a macro that will loop for two minutes, and check to see if something has changed every couple of seconds.

My macro opens an internet explorer window, and my intention is for it to check every couple of seconds whether the user has navigated to a particular part of the page, and then store the URL and exit the instance of internet explorer once it detects that this has happened.

Right now my loop doesn't work, it throws up an error on the if statement. I figure this is something I'm doing wrong with time loops, as this is something I'm new to.

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer: Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.Navigate URL

Dim wait_until As Date: wait_until = now + #12:02:00 AM#
Dim str_result As String

Do While wait_until <> now
    If ieApp.Document.Title = "Result" Then
        str_result = ieApp.LocationURL
        ieApp.Quit
        Set ieApp = Nothing
        Exit Do
    End If
    Application.Wait now + #12:00:02 AM#    
Loop
```

Comment: before checking for the document's title, first check the status of the navigation. `Do While ieApp.Busy......    Loop`

Comment: Add this just before you check `ieApp.Document.Title`: **`While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend`**. Also, your `Do While wait_until <> now` could potentially go into an endless loop if `now` is greater than `wait_until`. I would change that to: `Do While wait_until > now`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My issue is that IE won't be loading a single page. The user will navigate across multiple pages, until they hit one with a title that matches my specified title, and at that point I would like for the macro to pick up the necessary information and continue running. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: With While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend, I am getting automation error. The interface is unknown.

Comment: Change `IE` to `ieApp` as this is the variable you are declaring in your code.. **`While ieApp.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend`**